# What is the bare minimum I need to set up the Android SDK for Unity development?

Tags: unity, android

I want to import my Unity project to Android, and I need to download the Android SDK, but I do not want to download any unnecessary components.

Do I need to download all platforms, or just the latest one? I am worried about the size of Android 7.1.1 (API Level 25); the SDK Manager reports this as the latest version, but I am not sure.

I only want to import my project for Android smartphones, with no plan of publishing it. I do not want to build to Android TV or Android Wear, for example. Do I need to download all of the contents under the specific platform? I ask because there are Android TV and Android Wear system images, and the files can get quite large.

Comment: I found severe formatting issues with your question, and often simply listing a series of questions can have bad reception, so I reformed your question to pose a *main* question, and offer your *additional* questions as elements to that main question. Regardless, my answer should answer everything. I hope you do not mean Android Studio when you say "I downloaded the build tools". For someone that is worried about download size, you may have overshot your minimum requirement by about 1.2GB

Comment: I would like to add that *I wish I had of found a question like this with a suitable answer when I was in this boat*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you will need is the actual SDK Manager. [You can download the command line version from the official website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads), but [I found a link to the Windows GUI version](https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe) via [a helpful Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505709/how-do-i-download-the-android-sdk-without-downloading-an-android-studio). The official link should provide the GUI version for both Mac OS and Linux. As of this answer, this download is 145Mb.

Note that if you intend to use Android Studio at some point, [you should just download Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads). This will come with the SDK Manager, though it will greatly increase the size of your download. Android Studio is currently quoted at *1, 674Mb*, which is grossly oversized, in comparison to the other files and the simple fact that it is *not* a requirement.

If you do not have it, you will also need to install the Java Development Kit. The current version is about 200Mb<sup>1</sup>, and you will need to have it installed for the SDK Manager to complete it's installation.

---

From here, your actually on easy street. You should only need the *latest* SDK Platform. As of this answer, that version is API 25, also known as Android Nougat 7.1.1. This file is listed as exactly 81.5Mb.

Since you are already in the SDK Manager, it would help to *also* download the Android USB Driver. You will find this under "Extras", at a meager 8.3Mb. These drivers are often required in order to play test your games, using [the Unity Remote app](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html).

---

***Do I need to download the latest version?***

Yes and no. With each API release, Google have added more features and change to how the API works. If your project only used features up to API Level 15, for example, you would only need to install API Level 15. It is far easier to simply keep up to date than to ensure you have the API up to the level you require. [According to Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html), the bare minimum required is API Level 9, also known as Android Gingerbread 2.3.

***What if my players have an older version of Android?***

Older versions of android should still support *the language* of newer APIs - they just won't necessarily support the newer *features*. This *is* something you want to take into account; if only to ensure that you build your game to the correct *minimum API level*. You may also want to consider [the percentage of users using each API level](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).

***Do I need to download the additional images?***

No. The additional images are merely *device images*. If you were to be using Android Studio, and you wanted to run your application on a particular hardware emulator, that is when you would need to have the appropriate images installed.

***I am making a game for the phone - don't I need the phone images?***

No. Assuming you *have* an android phone, you should use your *physical* phone to test your game. The image is only for running emulated Android on your computer; to my knowledge, it still requires being run from Android Studio, and it is known to be a bit unpredictable in regards to performance.

***All in all, what are the damages?***

Assuming the bare necessities, including the USB drivers, you need the following:

- Android SDK Manager: 145Mb
- Java Development Kit: 200Mb
- Latest SDK Platform: 81.5Mb
- Android USB Drivers:  8.3Mb

Assuming you have already installed the Android SDK Manager, you only have a meager 89.8Mb of download left to complete. Assuming you start from scratch, your looking at a download of 434.8Mb. *This is still less than 30% of the download required to use Android Studio*, the official Android development software.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Linux and Mac versions are considerably smaller.</sub>

Comment: Why would he need the jdk and android studio? He uses Unity

Comment: @Bálint, as I say in my answer, if you *intend* to use Android Studio, its worth just downloading it all in one (Android Studio installer includes the SDK Manager that you *do* need). You need the JDK because the SDK Manager will not install without it. No SDK Manager, no SDK. Actually, I am pretty sure you still need the JDK to *build* for Android, even if you did get the SDK (If you can find a way to get the SDK without the manager, though, please post so as an answer). *I do specifically say this, in my answer*. I assume you skimmed through it, and only read the bottom section?

Comment: In reality, the entire JDK and SDK Manager section is completely irrelevant *to the actual asker*. They actually say they already have the SDK Manager. But we should be trying to answer the question for *future* users, aswell, so I felt it was worth adding the *first* step in "what do I need to download".

Comment: Doesn't make sense since the the question is for Unity development. You should trim everything that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @DH, I would recommend looking into Android development with Unity. The user is asking what they *need* for the Unity development. Given that they are not telling us specifically what they wish to do, all is relevant. The *Android Studio* element is a bit of a stretch, but it is minimal, and relevant to the fact that the user appears to have reported already downloading it (thus the clarification that you do NOT need it). All additional questions are directed at specific questions the asker originally asked. As stated in my comment on the question, I summarised the users original question list

Comment: (cont). to counter broad close-votes